# Uses of custom annotations, how to

Tags: java, annotations

Suppose you set up a custom annotation

```
public @interface ThreadSafe {
}
```

To indicate to the reader of your code that classes or methods are in fact Thread Safe

Other then a variant of a comment, how else can these types of custom annotations be used?

Comment: The answers here go a long way to answering your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341930/use-cases-for-implementing-annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just asking about potential applications of such an annotation, here's a few off the top of my head...

- Reflective code might take advantage of the thread-safety of annotated methods.  For example, Guava's `EventBus` uses an [`@AllowConcurrentEvents`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/eventbus/AllowConcurrentEvents.html) annotation as a hint for its `EventBus` framework.
- Static analysis tools can use annotations as hints -- either that a method *should* have a certain property, or that users of this method can assume a certain property.  For example, a static analysis tool might perform extra checks on methods annotated `@ThreadSafe` to make sure they are, in fact, thread safe.
- You could design preprocessors that might identify optimization opportunities that are only available because a specific method is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Such annotations can bring information that could be used to improve the efficiency of algorithms. The [RandomAccess](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) interface is used for this purpose.