# annotation represent another annotation

Tags: java, annotations

Is it possible to have an custom annotation that do the same work as another annotation ?

For example if I write @MyCustomAnnotation like I have write @override !

Comment: is there any reason you would want to? The annotations give a good indication to other developers as to what you are doing, if you change them for your own words they will mean nothing to other developer anymore.

Comment: exactly ... if the annotation name change you have to change all occurrence of that annotation in your code but if I was able to have it override I will only changed one time !

Comment: There are many use cases, like to make all `@Api` methods also `@SuppressWarning("unused")` (or to force them @NotNull), to make `@OldApi` also `@Deprecated`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely no support for inheritance with Annotations. See: [Is there something like Annotation Inheritance in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761513/is-there-something-like-annotation-inheritance-in-java)

So without that, unless some framework chose to provide extensibility around its annotation processing, you would have a lot of trouble achieving such an effect.