# Spring - how to rename @Bean

Tags: java, spring

How do you define an annotation in Spring that is semantically equivalent to `@Bean`, but has another name?

(Why? I'm building a DSL in which the functionality would fit, but it would greatly benefit from naming the annotation more closely to the role it plays in the library).

Comment: if it's supposed to be a Bean, what name do you think you can come up to which 'll be closer to the role it plays than Bean does?

Comment: @Stultuske `@MyEnhancedBean`? just sayin...

Comment: `@ExportMe`, for instance. Tie up a couple of dependencies together and then export the whole graph (e.g. to JSON), starting from one of them.

Comment: create your annotation that extends @bean.

Comment: @Antoniossss What a useless comment. Either you can help, or you can't. If the latter is the case, please don't spam.

Comment: Contrary to @Antoniossss suggestion, I don't believe you can extend an annotation.  Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761513/is-there-something-like-annotation-inheritance-in-java/18585833#18585833

Comment: @Cuga ihh i didnt know that - thought it works like simple interfaces ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well... It was as easy as:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Bean
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
}
```