# Does order of annotations matter in SB application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

It seems to me that having annotations in different order breaks my build.

[Does annotations order matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582135/does-annotations-order-matter)

Answers from above say, in general, annotations order should not matter. In my case it is breaking.

### This is module commons

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "calculatorEnabled", havingValue = "true")
@Component
class Calculator {

// some logic
}
```

```
@ConditionalOnBean(Calculator.class)
@Service
class CalculationService {

    private final Calculator calculator;

    @Autowired
    public CalculationService(final Calculator calculator) {
        this.calculator = calculator;
    }
 // some logic
}
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/calculations", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ConditionalOnBean(CalculationService.class)
@RestController
class CalculationController {

}
```

### let there be another module - advanced-calculations

which has module **commons** as a dependency (maven dependency).

Please, note, there are two maven modules on purpose. 
So `CalculationController` is available in other modules that use **commons** dependency.

Now, let me have two tests in **advanced-calculations**. (Again, I decided to test `CalculationController`) in another module.

I know that it is better to have tests in the module that actually defines a component, but **commons** module was written by other team long time ago; and for now we have to use it.

I want to make sure if we update version of **commons**, the app should not break (API should not change). Therefore, I added integration tests for `CalculationContrioller` into **advanced-calculation** module.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = [AdvancedCalculationApplication.class],properties = ["calculatorEnabled=true" ])
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
AdvancedCalculationsITTest extends Specification {

}
```

and

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = [AdvancedCalculationApplication.class],properties = ["calculatorEnabled=" ])
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
AdvancedCalculationsITTestsDisabled extends Specification {

}
```

`mvn clean install` fails because `AdvancedCalculationsITTest` fails. Error cannot autowire `CalculationController` because there is no candidate `calculationService`.

However, when I change slightly order of annotations, it works

```
@ConditionalOnBean(CalculationService.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/calculations", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@RestController
class CalculationController {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I will update this answer**, but a bit later.

For me TODO.
(I will make a demo and add a link to github and put some code examples).

Your ideas and suggestions are welcome!

I have 2 custom annotations (RUNTIME) on a method: one annotation that makes a method always to throw an exception `@Exceptional`, another `@Catchable` that always catches an exception. Let this method return `void` for simplicity. By placing these annotations in different order, you should get a different result.

```
@Catchable
@Exceptional
public void processAction() {
    // There is nothing that throws an exception.
    safeStatement1();
    safeStatement2();

    safeStatementN();
}
```

vs

```
@Exceptional
@Catchable
public void processAction() {
    // There is nothing that throws an exception.
    safeStatement1();
    safeStatement2();

    safeStatementN();
}

By having these annotations in different order, the result should be different.
```

Comment: I've been waiting 2 years for your updated answer