# Java Generics and Annotations: Type-Safe

Tags: java, generics, annotations

I know that I can do something like:

```
public class AbstractDao<T extends Bean> {

}
```

In this case, Bean is an class or interface.

I was wondering if is there a way to do this with annotations, like:

```
public class AbstractDao<T extends javax.persistence.Entity> {

}
```

Is something like this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no inheritance in annotations, so it's not possible.

Have a look at the answers to the similar question here:

[Why is not possible to extend annotations in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624084/why-is-not-possible-to-extend-annotations-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

No. The Java Language Specification [says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4) that type variables can only be constrained to extend / implement particular classes or interfaces. Since annotating a class does not cause the class to extend or implement a particular type, you can't constrain by annotation.