# Using annotation attributes in meta-annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-annotations

I created the following annotation to only activate test methods, if the given file (of `fileName` attribute) exists in the `data.scans.path` directory (configured in Spring's `application.yml`):

```java
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@EnabledIf(
    value = "#{new java.io.File(\"${data.scans.path}\", \"R000008-ueberraschungsei4\").isDirectory()}",
    loadContext = true
)
public @interface EnabledWhenScanDirExists {
    String fileName() default "R000008-ueberraschungsei4";
}
```

This works for the hard-coded file with name `R000008-ueberraschungsei4`, but, the `fileName` attribute is not used. I wanna change that. I tried to figure out how to use it in the `@EnabledIf` meta annotation. I found the possibility to use the attribute as a full parameter in a meta annotation via `@AliasFor` in Spring (f.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087467/passing-annotation-properties-to-meta-annotations)).
But from what I understood, I would think I can't use the `@AliasFor` annotation only for a small part of the `@EnabledIf.value()` attribute.
Is that correct? Is there any other way to do it?
Initially I tried things like this, but none of them worked:

```java
value = "#{new java.io.File(\"${data.scans.path}\", fileName()).isDirectory()}",
```