# property mockMvc has not been initialized when I use my custom meta-annotaion

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, spring-boot-test, mockmvc, meta-annotation

For each controller I have following test class:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = [MyFirstController::class])
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@Import(JacksonConfig::class)
class MyFirstControllerTest {
...
```

For another one it will be almost the same:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = [MySecondController::class])
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@Import(JacksonConfig::class)
class MySecondControllerTest {
...
```

I was inspired by spring boot annotation([for example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.java)) which contains a lot of nested annotation. So I want to create annotation to replace all 3 annotations in the way like this.

```
@MyWebMvcTest(controllers = [MySecondController::class])
class MySecondControllerTest { 
   ...
```

So based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087467/passing-annotation-properties-to-meta-annotations/36527889#36527889) I've created:

```
@WebMvcTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@Import(JacksonConfig.class)
public @interface MyWebMvcTest {
    @AliasFor(annotation = WebMvcTest.class, attribute = "controllers")
    Class<?>[] value() default {};
}
```

and test:

```
@MyWebMvcTest(MyController::class)
class MyControllerTest {
```

But I see the error during test startup:

```
lateinit property mockMvc has not been initialized
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mockMvc has not been initialized
```

### Update

Thanks for Alexander Radchenko answer I've added retention policy:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@WebMvcTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@Import(JacksonConfig.class)
public @interface MyWebMvcTest {
    @AliasFor(annotation = WebMvcTest.class, attribute = "controllers")
    Class<?>[] value() default {};
}
```

It definitely should be added but unfortunately it is not enough. I see the similar error.

**If anyone interested in MRE(please notice the branch name )** - https://github.com/gredwhite/springboottestconfigissue_demo/tree/feature/meta-annnotation-for-test/src/test/kotlin/com/example/demo/controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom annotation with default retention CLASS is not available to Spring processors. You need to set RUNTIME retention:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyWebMvcTest {
  ...
}
```

Another issue is that you put `MyWebMvcTest` (implemented on Java) to the folder `src/main/kotlin`. You have 2 options:

- move annotation to `src/test/java`
- convert it to Kotlin