# Type hierarchy in java annotations

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations, hierarchy

I am facing problem with creating some metadata structure inside annotations. We are using annotations for define special attributes for hibernate entity attributes but it might be usable everywhere.
I want to create condition which represent these structure:

```
attribute1 = ...
OR
  (attribute2 = ...
   AND
   attribute3 = ...)
```

Problem is that I need to define some "tree" structure using this annotations. Here is some design I want to reach:

```
@interface Attribute {
  ... some attributes ...
}

@interface LogicalExpression {
}

@interface OR extends LogicalExpression {
  Attribute[] attributes() default {};
  LogicalExpression logicalExpressions() default {};
}

@interface AND extends LogicalExpression {
  Attribute[] attributes() default {};
  LogicalExpression logicalExpressions() default {};
}

@interface ComposedCondition {
  Attribute[] attributes() default {};
  LogicalExpression logicalExpressions() default {};
}
```

All these annotation I want to use according to this example:

```
public class Table {

  @ComposedCondition(logicalExressions = {
    @OR(attributes = {@Attribute(... some settings ...)}, 
        logicalExpressions = {
          @AND(attributes = {@Attribute(...), @Attribute(...)})
        })
  }
  private String value;

}
```

I know that inheritance in that way I defined in the annotation definition above is not possible. But how can I consider my annotations AND, OR to be in one "family"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check [Why it is not possible to extends annotations in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624084/why-is-not-possible-to-extend-annotations-in-java)

But you can create meta annotations that can be used on annotation to create groups of annotations.

```
    @LogicalExpression
@interface OR {
    Attribute[] attributes() default {};
    LogicalExpression logicalExpressions() default {};
}
```

But this will not help you with your second problem ie. use `LogicalExpression` as a Parent.

But you can do something like below. Declare `LogicExpression` as `enum`  This way you can use single `enum` and various set of  `Attributes` to execute conditions.

e.g. If you want to execute `AND`, `OR` condition then you can pass `LogicExpression.AND`, `LogicExpression.OR` and use `orAttributes()` method to execute `OR` condition and `andAttributes()` to execute `AND` condition

```
public enum LogicExpression {
OR,AND,NOT;
}


@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
public @interface ComposedCondition {
LogicExpression[] getExpressions() default {};
Attributes[] orAttributes() default {};
   Attributes[] andAttributes() default {};..
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not help me. I need to define structure through some general LogicalExpression list but using specific AND, OR maybe NOT or other expressions.

Comment: Updated the answer I think this  definitely satisfies your purpose.

Comment: It is nice idea, but still this solution has its own limits. But your solution brings me another idea - I may implement it in NODE form. Node will contain type of logical expression applied on current level and list of Attributes and list of children Nodes.

Comment: Yes. I guess that will be also better solution.

Comment: But now I realize that there occur recursive dependency on children nodes which causes: "Cycle detected: the annotation type Node cannot contain attributes of the annotation type itself". So this is still not final solution. I hope there will be some easy workaround

Comment: Can you please show me what you have done? Answer your own question.

Comment: No I didn't mean that I meant you can add another answer with your code. :)

Comment: I started another thread, because it is different issue: [Java annotation recursive dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296452/java-annotation-recursive-dependency)