# Change annotation processor dynamically

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

Following sample is just to explain the my implementation, please have a look at and let me know if i can get any answers for this

I have created a annotation Dispenser

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Dispenser {

}
```

I have two classes of type dispenser above

1. Milk Dispenser --
2. Drink Dispenser --

   ```
   @Dispenser
   class MilkDispenser{

       public void releaseDrink()
   }

   @Dispenser
   class DrinkDispenser{

       public void releaseDrink()
   }
   ```

and i have a class  DispenserProcessor extends AbstractProcessor

Everything looks fine until unless i found a better implmentation of DispenserProcessor from the client they have their own implementation
I cannot copy their code so i need a way switch to that dispenserProcessor developed by the client instead of mine

**Question, is there any way @MyDispenser can extend their @ClientDispenser**

Comment: Thanks Samuel, I understand as of now there is no reason of using it. So i changed my requirement a little and changed the implementation to use Dynamic proxies to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you would have to use annotation inheritance to support this, but annotation inheritance is not supported.

More info here: [Why is not possible to extend annotations in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624084/why-is-not-possible-to-extend-annotations-in-java)