# How to extend annotations in Java?

Tags: java, annotations, android-annotations

I'm using Android Annotations library and there is `@UIThread` annotation, which takes an optional argument `propagation`. I always use this annotation with `REUSE` value of this parameter:

```
@UiThread(propagation = UiThread.Propagation.REUSE)
void doSomething() {
}
```

So can I make somehow my own annoation `@UIThreadReuse` which would extend the `@UIThread` annotation and pass `REUSE` as a parameter? So I could just write like this:

```
@UiThreadReuse
void doSomething() {
}
```

Comment: Java does not allow to extend annotations, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624084/why-is-not-possible-to-extend-annotations-in-java

Comment: The title is not correct. This is about annotation processing code generation tool, and the OP wants to add a new annotation with a narrowed generation behavior of an existing annotation.

Comment: or, you could see the composing part of annotations - http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/12/composing-java-annotations.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible right now. But in the near future we will support plugins for AndroidAnnotations, so you will be able to add new annotations and corresponding code generators easily.