# Is it possible to create my own Custom Annotation that act as Spring @Controller annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my Spring application I have controllers with two annotations:

@Controller - Spring annotation

@AdminPanelController - my annotation

Is it possible change my annotation so I can used if with out the need to place @Controller in addition?

I want that Spring will process my annotation as @Controller annotation.

Comment: Can you provide a code example of what you are wanting to do? It's a little hard to tell what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is missing some detailed explanation on your needs, but my assumption is that you do not want to bother putting both your annotation and  @Controller on your admin panel controllers. You want Spring-MVC you understand that any @AdminPanelController is-a @Controller.
This is exactly what @RestController annotation in Spring 4.0 any @RestController is-a @Controller (See the source [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.0.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.java)).
So your @AdminPanelController annotation should be similar to the one below

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Controller
public @interface AdminPanelController {
    String value() default "";
}
```

So although java annotation does not support inheritance in the sense we expect (see [Why is not possible to extend annotations in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624084/why-is-not-possible-to-extend-annotations-in-java)) this will work for spring-mvc thanks to [meta-annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-meta-annotations) (I tested this with 4.1).

Answer (score 3):

I'm reasonably sure that all you need is to annotate the AdminPanelController with @Controller