# how to declare an Array of Object in annoation?

Tags: java

Given that we can't create a hierarchy of annoations,
[why-is-not-possible-to-extend-annotations-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624084/why-is-not-possible-to-extend-annotations-in-java)

how to decalare an array of object to store an ordered list of different annotations

```
public @interface View {
    Object[] elements(); 
//Invalid type Object[] for the annotation attribute View.elements; only 
primitive type, String, Class, annotation, enumeration are permitted
 or 1-dimensional arrays thereof
}
Elements could be @Field, @Tab, @Listing .... but i need to know the order
```

The needs is that i have a xml hierarchy tree like this

```
<view id="StkEntranceVoucher" name="StkEntranceVoucher" >
   <listingHeader />
   <listing >
      <ref mode="vp" target="titleText"/>
      <ref mode="vp" target="voucherNumber"/>      
   </listing>
   <panel>
      <tab>
         <tab>            
            <panel>
                 <field name="title" />
            </panel>
            <field name="titleText" />
            <field name="voucherNumber">
        </tab>
      </tab>
    </panel>
</view>
```

i want to be able to generate this XML config, with anotation configuration on the model :
i am already able to do this

```
@View(queryFilter=@QueryFilter(orderBy="(?).id.num"), detailSize="580px",
    listingHeader=@ListingHeader(actions="printAll"),
    listing={ "id.num", "reference", "onDate", "fromSection", "supplier", 
                "totalField", "buyOrder.id.num", "buyOrder.onDate", "receiptVcr.id.num", "receiptVcr.onDate",
                "prdExitOrd.id.num", "prdExitOrd.onDate", "invExtract.id.num", "invExtract.onDate" }, 
    tabs={
        @Tab(name="GeneralTab",
        SubTabs={ 
            @SubTab( name="HeaderTab",
                style =@Style(type=StlType.print, colWidths={"50", "400"}, width="450", marginB=2, marginT=8 ),
                fields={                
                    @Field(name="titleText", mode="p", valueExpr="#{bean.mapID( wcx,'reportTitle')}", expectedType=String.class,
                        style=@Style(type=StlType.print, align="center", bold=true, fontSize=16, marginT=20, paddingB=4, paddingL=4, paddingR=4, paddingT=4, textAlign="center", width="200")),             
                    @Field(name="voucherNumberText", mode="p", valueExpr="#{bean.mapID( wcx,'VoucherNum')} : #{(?).id.num} #{bean.mapID( wcx,'VoucherOf')} #{util.format((?).onDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')}", expectedType=String.class,
                        style=@Style(type=StlType.print, align="center", fontSize=10, textAlign="center" )),                        
                    @Field(name="id.sgSr", mode="", queryFilter=true),  
                    @Field(name="id.num", width="60px", mode="v"),
                    @Field(name="reference"),
                    @Field(name="onDate", mode="v"),                    
                    @Field(name="fromSection"),
                    @Field(name="supplier") }
                ),
            @SubTab( name="ItemsTab", subView=
                @SubView( name="StkEntranceVoucherItem", entityType=StkInputVoucherItem.class, editable=true, 
                    listingFields={ 
                        @Field(name="id.vcr", mode="", queryFilter=true),
                        @Field(name="id.item", width="60px", codeLabel=true),
                        @Field(name="id.item.label", width="150px", mode="rvp"),
                        @Field(name="quantity", width="60px"),
                        @Field(name="id.item.measureUnit", width="50px", mode="rpv"),
                        @Field(name="unitPrice", width="60px"),
                        @Field(name="amount", width="80px", mode="rvp", 
                                calcExpr="#{(?).quantity*(?).unitPrice}"),
                        @Field(name="batch", jsfCpn=JsfCpn.button, linkedViewName="StkInputVoucherBatch", 
                                styleClass="no_padding", width="24px"), 
                        @Field(name="comment", width="100px") }) ),
            @SubTab( name="StkEntranceVoucherTotalTab", style=@Style(css="float:right;"),  
                fields={ 
                    @Field( name="totalField", ofColFooter="amount", mode="rvp",
                        valueExpr="(?).amount", expectedType=Double.class,
                        calcExpr="#{(?)==bean.record?bean.sum(':amount'):(?).amount}") }) 
            })
    })
```

but its not fully the same syntax because here i use an array of @Tab and an array of @Field but i can't have an array of different annotations

Comment: You can't. That's what the error message tells you.

Comment: thank's, but what is the right way to store an ordered list in annotation?

Comment: As @JBNizet you cannot do this. However if you explain what do you want to achieve we will probably be able to assist you with other solution.

Comment: i am not very good in english so, its hard to explain all

Comment: You can use an array, but it must be an array of primitive types, Strings, Classes, annotations, or enumerations.

Comment: it will be perfect, if it is an array of annotation but i already try it, it looks impossible, but it must be an array of different annoation

Comment: @NassimMOUALEK, take a look on my answer. Does it look relevant for you?

Comment: But it always an array of the same annotation

Answer (score 0):

I hope, I got your idea. You want to achieve something like the following:

```
@MyAnnotationContainer(
{@MyAnnotation1, @MyAnntation2, @MyAnntation3}
)
class MyClass {}
```

It is impossible in java. But you actually do not need this. You can put your annotations directly on the class:

```
@MyAnnotation1
@MyAnnotation2
@MyAnnotation3
class MyClass {}
```

Now you can get declared annotations from your class, so that you will actually get the ordered list that you want. Obviously you can filter the relevant annotations only and omit other (not yours) annotations.

Comment: You did understand the need, but the solution is not adequat, thank you anyway

Comment: The solution must be hierarchical

Comment: Hierarchy cannot be achieved directly with annotations. However, again, this sounds like a famous xy problem. Try to explain what is your primary task. Probably we will suggest you better solution.

Comment: i add more details, i hope you understand what i am doing