# Java Annotations - how to create an array?

Tags: java, annotations

I tried to create a "map" using nested JAVA annotations.

```
public @interface EnvInstance {
    Env env();
    Instance instance();
}

public @interface Configuration {
    String description();
    EnvInstance[] envInstances() default {};
}

@Configuration(description = "Test", envInstances = {
    @EnvInstance(env = Env.CERT, instance = Instance.FIRST),
    @EnvInstance(env = Env.INTEGR, instance = Instance.SECOND),
    @EnvInstance(env = Env.PROD, instance = Instance.FIRST),
    ...
}
)
public class TestObject {

}
```

It seems to work but there is one thing I don't know how to achieve. I want to create two default sets of `envInstances` configuration so I can type:

```
@Configuration(description = "Test", envInstances = SET_ONE)
public class TestObject {
}
```

or

```
@Configuration(description = "Test", envInstances = SET_TWO)
public class TestObject {
}
```

Is there a possibility to create a static array of inner annotations or something like this and pass it to the outer annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no way to extract this duplication.

You cannot supply an array value to annotation from constant ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java)). It is also not possible to create annotation that extends another annotation ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624084/why-is-not-possible-to-extend-annotations-in-java)).

I don't know the context, but have you considered passing this information into the object itself, and storing it as a field, rather than via annotations?

Another potential solution that might work is to make these classes implement a marker interface and annotate an interface instead. Annotations however are not inherited. If you can modify your parser (or whatever is reading the annotations), you could do something like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface X {
    String[] value();
}

@X({"a", "b", "c"})
interface AnInterface {}

public static class TestClass implements AnInterface {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // annotations are not inherited, empty array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(TestClass.class.getAnnotations()));

    // check if TestClass is annotated with X and get X.value()
    Arrays.stream(TestClass.class.getAnnotatedInterfaces())
            .filter(type -> type.getType().equals(AnInterface.class))
            .map(type -> (Class<AnInterface>) type.getType())
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(anInterface -> {
                String[] value = anInterface.getAnnotation(X.class).value();
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(value));
            });
}
```

Comment: Not an option. :( I guess I will have to be forced to copy-paste all the configuration for every single environment for every single object. Anyway I see a nice functionality for incoming Java releases. ;)

Comment: I will wait couple hours for other answers. Maybe someone will figure it out. If not, I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: @aerion there is one more possibility but requires to modify the parser (or whatever reads the annotations). See my edit.

Comment: Clever but not very elegant and makes hard to override other configuration data. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a possibility to create a static array of inner annotations or something like this and pass it to the outer annotation?

No.  For primitive or string-valued annotation elements you *can* declare a `static final` constant somewhere else and refer to that in the annotation, but this does not work for array-valued elements.

The [Java language specification section 9.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1) mandates that any value specified for an array-valued annotation element that does not *syntactically* start with an opening brace must be treated as shorthand for a single-element array, i.e. the parser treats

```
@Configuration(description = "Dupa", envInstances = SET_ONE)
```

as if it said

```
@Configuration(description = "Dupa", envInstances = {SET_ONE})
```

and fails because you're trying to set `envInstances` to an `EnvInstance[][]` instead of an `EnvInstance[]`.

---

The precise wording (my bold on the sections that apply to this case):

> It is a compile-time error if the element type is not commensurate with the element value. An element type `T` is commensurate with an element value `V` if and only if one of the following is true:
>
> - **`T` is an array type `E[]`**, and either:
>
>   - **If `V` is a ConditionalExpression** or an Annotation, then **`V` is commensurate with `E`**; or
>   - If `V` is an ElementValueArrayInitializer, then each element value that `V` contains is commensurate with `E`.
>
> [snip]
>
> - `T` is not an array type, and the type of `V` is assignment compatible (§5.2) with `T`, and:
>
>   - If `T` is a primitive type or `String`, then `V` is a constant expression (§15.28).
>
> [snip]