# Is it possible to add custom property to java bean validation annotation?

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

Like that

```
@NotNull(code=10000)
@Size(min=5, max=10, code=10001)
```

Java bean validation has 3 properties: message, payload and groups. I wanna add a new one: `code`.

I've checked some docs, like https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkfgx.html. It seems not possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer to your question: No, you can't just add an extra field, nor can you use inheritance too add the extra field. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1624084/2357233) which explains why Java doesn't allow inheritance with annotations.

What you'll have to do is create your own particular version of the `@Size` annotation. But you should be able to apply the `@Size` annotation to your custom annotation so that `@Size` is checked automatically when you run your validations.

Your annotation would probably look something like this:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ReportAsSingleViolation
//The only downside of this approach 
//is that you have to hardcode your min and max values
@Size(min=5, max=10)
public @interface CodedSize {
    String message() default "{Default Validation Message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
    int code() default 0;
}
```

If you wanted to specify the size as well in the annotation, you could do that, and write a custom validator that validates your annotation.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = { CodedSizeValidator.class })
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CodedSize {
    String message() default "{Default Validation Message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
    int minSize() default 5;
    int maxSize() default 10;
    int code() default 0;
}
```

Then your custom validator looks something like this:

```
public class CodedSizeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CodedSize, String> {

    private int minSize;
    private int maxSize;
    private int code;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CodedSize constraintAnnotation){
        this.minSize = constraintAnnotation.minSize();
        this.maxSize = constraintAnnotation.maxSize();
        this.code = constraintAnnotation.code();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        if(value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            //if a null or empty value is valid, then set it here.
            isValid = true;   
        } else {
            //Logic here to determine if your value is valid by size constraints.
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

I used `String` because that seemed the most applicable, but you could easily use `Number`, or even a generic type to allow you to use this annotation on more than one field. The advantage of doing it this way is that if you want to add a null check in with this validation, you can do so.

The `ConstraintValidatorContext` can be used to build out your error message if multiple validations fail. You can make this as detailed as you want, but be aware that this code can spaghetti-fy very quickly.