# Method annotation inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, annotations

So, my problem is the following, I'm using annotations to tag the methods of a class.

My main annotation is `@Action` and I need a stronger annotation for specific methods that is `@SpecificAction`.

All the methods annotated with `@SpecificAction` must be annotated as `@Action`.
My idea is to have `@SpecificAction` annotated with `@Action`.

```
@Action
[other irrelevant annotations]
public @interface SpecificAction{}
```

with

```
@SpecificAction
public void specificMethod(){}
```

I would expect `specificMethod.isAnnotationPresent(Action.class)` to be true, but it isn't.

How could I make it so that the `@Action` annotation is "inherited"?

Comment: `@Action @SpecificAction public void specificMethod(){}`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624084/why-is-not-possible-to-extend-annotations-in-java

Comment: You can work around the problem by adding a property such as `String type() default "base";` or `boolean isSpecific default false;` into your annotation.

Comment: @Michael That is what I didn't want to do (I'm lazy :) )

Comment: @MickMnemonic That is what I did, but I'm somehow sad I couldn't have that "inheritence :p"

Answer (score 3):

As @assylias's link says, the annotations can't be inherited, but you can use the composition, and search recursively your target annotation like this:

```
public static class AnnotationUtil {

    private static <T extends Annotation> boolean containsAnnotation(Class<? extends Annotation> annotation, Class<T> annotationTypeTarget, Set<Class<? extends Annotation>> revised) {
        boolean result = !revised.contains(annotation);
        if (result && annotationTypeTarget != annotation) {
            Set<Class<? extends Annotation>> nextRevised = new HashSet<>(revised);
            nextRevised.add(annotation);
            result = Arrays.stream(annotation.getAnnotations()).anyMatch(a -> containsAnnotation(a.annotationType(), annotationTypeTarget, nextRevised));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static <T extends Annotation> boolean containsAnnotation(Class<? extends Annotation> annotation, Class<T> annotationTypeTarget) {
        return containsAnnotation(annotation, annotationTypeTarget, Collections.emptySet());
    }

    public static <T extends Annotation> Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, ? extends Annotation> getAnnotations(Method method, Class<T> annotationTypeTarget) {
        return Arrays.stream(method.getAnnotations()).filter(a -> containsAnnotation(a.annotationType(), annotationTypeTarget)).collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a.annotationType(), Function.identity()));
    }
}
```

If you have:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Action {
}

@Action
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface SpecificAction {
}

@Action
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface ParticularAction {
}

public class Foo{
    @SpecificAction
    @ParticularAction
    public void specificMethod() {
         // ...
    }
}
```

You can use like this: `AnnotationUtil.getAnnotations(specificMethod, Action.class);` And this'll return a Map: `{interface foo.ParticularAction=@foo.ParticularAction(), interface foo.SpecificAction=@foo.SpecificAction()}`

Comment: The idea indeed crossed my mind, I was looking for a way to avoid doing that and not having to write the recursion. But as it was said in the link, it is good to know that there no such inheritance!