# custom annotation parametrized inherit other annotation

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

I have one parametrized annotation (`@MiTag1` in this case). And I want to create a new annotation (`@MiTag2`), that extends `@MiTag1` and other annotation, and I want that the value of `@MiTag1` "be extended" by the value of `@MiTag2`

With my code example, `@MiTag2("bla")` have to be the same as `@MiTag1("bla")`, but without hardcode "bla" inside `@MiTag2`.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MiTag1 {

    /**
     * The resource key.
     *
     * @see Resources
     */
    String value();
}

@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MiTag1(value = THIS.VALUE)
public @interface MiTag2 {

    /**
     * The resource key.
     *
     * @see Resources
     */
    String value();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does not permit you to extend from another annotation. This is by design, as it would introduce a fairly complex type system. This question has been answer in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624084/why-is-it-not-possible-to-extend-annotations-in-java), but the important parts are:

> Why don’t you support annotation subtyping (where one annotation type
>   extends another)?
>
> It complicates the annotation type system, and makes it much more
>   difficult to write “Specific Tools”.
>
> …
>
> “Specific Tools” — Programs that query known annotation types of
>   arbitrary external programs. Stub generators, for example, fall into
>   this category. These programs will read annotated classes without
>   loading them into the virtual machine, but will load annotation
>   interfaces.

(original answer from *pedromarce*)

To bypass this problem, you can either annotate your target type with both annotations
`@MiTag1 @MiTag2` and set the default value of the *should inheriting* annotation to the value of the *parent annotation*.

Also, you can use composition over inheritence and add an annotation of type `@MiTag2` to `@MiTag2`.

Comment: "... add an annotation of type `@MiTag2` to `@MiTag2`". Could you provide an example?